# how to display my data in my tableView with Alamofire request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a JSON table with these data and I would like to get the title + oreview and then display them in my application but I am blocked after this condition and I don't know how to proceed, ideas?.
I use Alamofire for my request.

my tab json :

```
{"results":
[{"title":"The Predator",
  "poster_path":"\/wMq9kQXTeQCHUZOG4fAe5cAxyUA.jpg"
  "overview":"From the outer reaches of space to the small-town streets of suburbia, the hunt comes home. Now, the universe’s most lethal hunters are stronger, smarter and deadlier than ever before, having genetically upgraded themselves with DNA from other species. When a young boy accidentally triggers their return to Earth, only a ragtag crew of ex-soldiers and a disgruntled science teacher can prevent the end of the human race.",
  "release_date":"2018-09-13"}
```

my class Movie.swift :

```
   import UIKit

class Movie {
    var title: String
    var oreview: String

    public init(title: String, oreview: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.oreview = oreview
    }

    public init?(json: [String: Any]) {
        guard
            let title = json["title"] as? String,
            let oreview = json["oreview"] as? String else {
                return nil

        }

        self.title = title
        self.oreview = oreview
    }
}
```

My MovieTableVieWCell.swift :

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class MovieTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var posterView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var oreview: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func DescriptionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

}

extension MovieTableViewCell {
    func draw(movie: Movie) {
        self.title.text = "\(movie.title)"
        self.oreview.text = "\(movie.oreview)"
    }
}
```

My MovieViewController.swift :

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class MovieViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableMovie: UITableView!

    var movie: [Movie]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableMovie.register(UINib(nibName: "MovieTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Movie")

        self.tableMovie.delegate = self
        self.tableMovie.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.request()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    public func request() {
        let token = Token()
        Alamofire.request("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=\(token.getToken())").responseJSON { response in
            guard
                let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any]
                else {
                    return
            }

            print(json)
             self.tableMovie.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

extension Movie: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        let fields = [
            "title: \(self.title)",
            "oreview: \(self.oreview)",
            ]
        return fields.joined(separator: ",")
    }
}

extension MovieViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.movie?.count ?? 0
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Movie", for: indexPath) as! MovieTableViewCell
        if let mov = self.movie?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.draw(movie: mov)
        }
        return cell
    }
}

extension MovieViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did'nt set any value in **movie**.

First, you need to parse the response & extract the **results** which is an array of objects

```
guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any], let results = json["results"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
    return
}
```

Second, you need to convert array of objects to array of Movie & set it

```
self.movie = results.map { Movie(json: $0) }
```

Third, reload TableView

```
self.tableMovie.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, save the movie data in an array, have the data source return 1 section with `array.count` elements. The table view will then automatically ask for the elements, which you will give from the array. Have the table view reload the data when you obtain the results from your request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, post your json as code:

```
{"results":[
            {
             "title":"The Predator",
             "poster_path":"/wMq9kQXTeQCHUZOG4fAe5cAxyUA.jpg",
             "overview":"From the outer reaches of space to the small-town streets of suburbia, the hunt comes home. Now, the universe’s most lethal hunters are stronger, smarter and deadlier than ever before, having genetically upgraded themselves with DNA from other species. When a young boy accidentally triggers their return to Earth, only a ragtag crew of ex-soldiers and a disgruntled science teacher can prevent the end of the human race.",
             "release_date":"2018-09-13"
            }
           ]
}
```

Secondly, your json is corrupt. You don't have a comma between "....jpg" and "overview". You don't have your square brackets and curly brackets closed. Where did you get this json from?

Thirdly, you don't parse your json correctly, moreover, you're expecting the key to be called `"oreview"` while in json it is named `"overview"`.

Here's how you should do it:

Modify your Movie class:

```
class Movie {
    var title: String
    var overview: String

    public init(title: String, overview: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.overview = overview
    }

    class func buildFrom(json: [String: Any]) -> Movie? {

       let results = json["results"] as! [[String : Any]]
       guard let title = results[0]["title"] as? String, let overview = results[0]["overview"] as? String else { return nil }

       return Movie(title: title, overview: overview)

    }
}
```

Now get rid of all your code from the custom cell:

```
class MovieTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var posterView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var overview: UILabel!

}
```

Now, let's go to your viewController:

```
class MovieViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableMovie: UITableView!

    var movie: Movie?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableMovie.register(UINib(nibName: "MovieTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Movie")

        self.tableMovie.delegate = self
        self.tableMovie.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.request()
    }

    func request() {
        let token = Token()
        Alamofire.request("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=\(token.getToken())").responseJSON { response in
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
            self.movie = Movie.buildFrom(json: json)

            self.tableMovie.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

//UITableView Datasource & Delegate methods
extension MovieViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      if self.movie != nil {
         return 1
      }
      return 0
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Movie", for: indexPath) as! MovieTableViewCell
      cell.title = self.movie.title
      cell.overview = self.movie.overview

      return cell
   }
}
```

This should do it. In case you pasted your json incorrectly and it is actually a json with more than 1 movie inside, then there will be needed some changes in code. Let me know and I will change my answer. Also, don't forget to update your json in the question. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer, so yes I have to get more than one line, so I thought to myself what needs to change? the Movie class or the MovieViewController?
Because yes with what you gave me, it only displays the first line. Otherwise for the json I just made a mistake by copying it on the subject